# Where is sbt 1.4 folder?

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, sbt

I am following the sbt eclipse plugin installation guide [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbteclipse).  It tells me to create:

```
the global file (for version 0.13 and up) at ~/.sbt/SBT_VERSION/plugins/plugins.sbt
```

I go to `~/.sbt/` and can only see `1.0` and `boot` folders there.  `1.4` is nowhere to be seen.  Am I missing something?  1.4 is quite some versions away from 1.0 and I cannot think of a reason why the folder is missing.

Comment: `1.0` works for any `1.x.y` version of sbt.

Comment: The Eclipse Scala IDE is pretty much dead. I would recommend trying IntelliJ IDEA or Visual Studio Code instead.

Comment: I use Eclipse because some of the tutorials use it.  Anyways, things got more complicated and I had to get to `sbt` which is never intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, `1.0` works for any `1.x` version. If you check sbt documentation for [Global Settings](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Global-Settings.html), you will see that it inambiguously refers to this location:

> Settings that should be applied to all projects can go in `$HOME/.sbt/1.0/global.sbt` (or any file in `$HOME/.sbt/1.0` with a `.sbt` extension). Plugins that are defined globally in `$HOME/.sbt/1.0/plugins/` are available to these settings.

Yes, this might be confusing, but the reason it is like that is that all `1.x` versions are binary compatible, so there was no reason in creating new directories for each minor version of sbt and it stayed on `1.0`. You can find more details about it in this issue: [sbt/sbt#3858](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3858#issuecomment-355867704)

@eed3si9n:

> It's intentional. sbt 1.x adopts Semantic Versioning. [...]
> Because of Semantic Versioning, bincompat is now denoted only by the first segment. We should've caught this early on and used 1 or something, but there were some code expecting (Int, Int), so we went with 1.0.

@dwijnand:

> As Eugene said, 1.0 is the binary API for the whole 1.x series. In retrospect I should've made it "1.x" (and properly dealt with the existing (Int, Int) type signature) instead of "1.0".

Comment: Thank you!  This has driven me nuts.